# My blog doesn't scroll horizontally when adjusted

Tags: html, web, scroll, browser, scrollbar

So I'm pretty new to all this coding stuff and I've been toying around with my blog to give it a better look. I found a template, messed with it a bit and think its all set. Then I realized when I shrink the browser, it gets all funky. Instead of adding the horizontal and vertical scroll bars, it just has the vertical scroll bar and then stacks the side bar under the main area.

I don't know how to go about fixing this. I was reading other pages and it says add stuff like overflow-x:scroll and whatnot but I don't know where that'd go.

The website is www.netstakeover.com

I'm not sure if you need parts of the code or if you can do the inspect element stuff with Chrome and figure it out. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the template you are using is responsive and has the "stacking" feature built in using @media queries :)

Comment: what it does is reads the size of the display, and if it is smaller than "x", it re-organizes everything based off of whatever the css is inside those media queries

Comment: Thanks for the quick  response! Is this something that I can change?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the css and completely remove the @media queries if you really didn't it want to be responsive like it is. the media queries are always at the very bottom of your stylesheet (or at least they should be)

Comment: Should I just take out anything that has "@media"?

Comment: If you are wanting to remove the responsiveness for different size browsers, yes, just remove anything with @media

Make sure you have a backup of your css file before you start removing things!

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much. Am I allowed to ask another question about it or no?